# How to find array on mongoose doc object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I interest How to find array in mongoose. for example: if I have this data:

```
[
   { nums: [2,3,1,4,5] },
   { nums: [2,3] },
   { nums: [1,2,3] },
   { nums: [2,3,1,4,5,10,9] },
   ....
]
```

and I want only know this array have or not: `[1,2,3,4,5]`. in this example I get first object: `{ nums: [2,3,1,4,5] }` and size of arrays must match

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check whether the `nums` property of an item in the array is equal to the array you're looking for:

```js
const arr = [
   { nums: [2,3,1,4,5] },
   { nums: [2,3] },
   { nums: [1,2,3] },
   { nums: [2,3,1,4,5,10,9] },
]

const lookFor = [1,2,3,4,5].sort().toString()
const contains = arr.some(e => e.nums.sort().toString() == lookFor);
console.log(contains);
```

Comment: Can I use this mongoose find query?

Comment: @begencharazow I'm not sure. Try it.