# Search mongoose array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create a social network. Now I have a problem. 
I have `Conversations` and `User` collection. Conversations collection schema this:

```
const conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   messages: [Object],
   recipients:[{
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'User'
    }] ,
   .....
})
```

I have `/findOrCreate` route for find recipients or create.

```
router.post( /findOrCreate, async ( req,res )=>{
  const { selectedUsers } = req.body;
  try{
   const found = await Conversation.find( { recipients: selected } ); // I cant find array. Problem there
   if(found) return res.status(200).json(found)
   else {
    // create document
    }  
  }
} )
```

How to find array in mongoose. For example if I have these `['1','3','4'], ['1','2','3','4'] , ...` and I my `selected = ['2','4','1',3]` I want to get this `['1','2','3','4']`.

Please help me.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you are wanting to check a set of arrays to see if one of the matches with `selected`?

If so, would this [SO Post satisfy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606357/16471349)?

it shares how to use `every` and `includes` to verify that an entry matches required

Comment: to relate to your case, `selected` === `target` in the SO post.

Comment: this question like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68747049/how-to-find-array-on-mongoose-doc-object/68747219#68747219) but I cant get correctly.